# Let $R$ be a finite ring. Show that $R$ has unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a finite ring that contains an element $a$, which is not a left divisor of zero, and an element $b$, which is not a right divisor of zero. Show that $R$ has unity.

Hint is that I should define two bijective mappings from $R$ to $R$.

So I defined $f:R \rightarrow R$ as $f(r)=ar$ and $g:R \rightarrow R$ as $g(r)=rb$.

Check if $f$ is injection: Suppose $f(r)=f(k)$. Then $ar=kr \Rightarrow ar-ak=0 \Rightarrow a(r-k)=0 \Rightarrow r-k=0$ (since $a$ is not a left divisor of zero) $\Rightarrow r=k$. So, $f$ is injective. Also, since $R$ is finite and $f$ is injective $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is surjective, hence bijection.

Similarly we show that $g$ is bijection.

But how to continue? Did I so far OK?

Comment: "$R$  is finite and $f$ is injective $\implies\  f$ is surjective."  Why is that?  I'm not saying it's false, but I don't see why it's true.

Comment: Its always true for finite sets.

Comment: Hint: Since $f$ is surjective there is some $e$ such that $f(e)=a$. Show that this is a left multiplicative identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is surjective, there is some $e \in R$ such that $ae = a$. We claim that $e$ is the desired unity.

For any $x \in R$ we have
$$f(ex) = aex = ax = f(x)$$
so $ex = x$.

In particular $eb = b$ so for any $x \in R$ we have
$$g(xe) = xeb = xb = g(x)$$
so $xe = x$.